# How can I write a method parameter when I'm calling another method?

Tags: ruby, parameters

Sorry I'm a big beginner in Ruby and I don't know if my title and my question makes sense...

Here my code :

```
class Account
  attr_reader :name, :balance
  def initialize(name, balance=100)
    @name = name
    @balance = balance
  end

  def display_balance
    pin_check
    puts "Hello #{name} ! Your balance is $ #{balance}."
  end

  private
  def pin
    @pin = 1234
  end

  def pin_check(pin_number)
    if @pin_number == @pin
      puts "Access authorized: pending transaction"
    else puts "Access denied: wrong PIN"
    end
  end
end

checking_account = Account.new("Saitama", 20_000)
checking_account.display_balance
```

What I’m trying to do is to automate the “pin check” in the other methods. My problem here is with the pin_check parameter : of course, the program is expecting an argument from this method but on my last line of code, I don’t know how to give it the 1234 argument expected… Is there any way to write correctly this last line of code to link display_balance and pin_check so as to giving the good argument to pin_check ?

I was thinking maybe write something like that but I know it doesn't work :

```
checking_account.display_balance.pin_check(1234)
```

How can I link both ? Thank you so much for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest thing to do would be to perform `pin_check` in the constructor, and then you don't have to worry about doing it for all methods. `pin_number` would be a constructor argument.

Another option would be to use something like `ActiveModel::Validations`, and add a validator that checks the PIN. Any client of your class would need to know to `validate` before performing any of the actions. That is the pattern used by Rails facilities such as ActiveRecord.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)

Sorry I'm a big begginner and I'm not sure to understand what you're saying about "contructor argument"... Do you mean perform it in the `initialize` method ?

About your second option, I don't think I can figure it out for now. Unfortunately, my Ruby skill is very low :(

Comment: replace `@pin_number == @pin` with `pin_number == pin`

Comment: Yes @Monsieur_Sboob I mean pass the `pin_number` as an argument to `initialize`, and perform the validation check immediately in the body of the initialize method.

Comment: Perfect it works, thanks for your help ! :)

Ok probably the best way indeed, I'm gonna try that !

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the pin into `display_balance` and pass it through to `pin_check`.

```
  def display_balance(pin:)
    pin_check(pin)
    puts "Hello #{name} ! Your balance is $ #{balance}."
  end
```

```
checking_account = Account.new("Saitama", 20_000)
checking_account.display_balance(pin: 1234)
```

Note that because `pin_check` only prints, the balance will always be displayed. You probably want it to [raise an exception](https://www.rubyguides.com/2019/06/ruby-rescue-exceptions/).

```
  def pin_check(pin_number)
    raise "Access denied: wrong PIN" unless pin_number == pin
  end
```

Note that it's `pin_number` and not `@pin_number`. `pin_number` is the variable containing what was passed into `pin_check`. `@pin_number` is an ["instance variable"](https://www.rubyguides.com/2019/07/ruby-instance-variables/) stored on the object.

***Update***: Also note that it's `pin` and not `@pin`. `@pin` will not be set unless `pin` is called.

---

It's probably better to pass the pin in once during object initialization and raise an error if it does not match. This guarantees no operations can happen without a pin check.

```
  attr_reader :name, :balance
  def initialize(name:, balance: 100, pin:)
    @name = name
    @balance = balance

    pin_check(pin)
  end

  private def pin_check(pin_try)
    raise "Access denied: wrong PIN" unless pin_try == @pin
  end
```

```
checking_account = Account.new(name: "Saitama", balance: 20_000, pin: 1234)
checking_account.display_balance
```

Note that I'm using [named arguments](https://www.rubyguides.com/2018/06/rubys-method-arguments/). This lets you add arguments, even optional ones, without having to remember what argument 3 was.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's very helpful and I'm learning so much :) However I still can't figure it out why (in your first example) the console displays "Access authorized" even if I'm calling a wrong parameter (ex : 1235 instead of 1234), any idea ?

I'll try the second part of your comment tomorrow ! It seems indeed much more efficient ;)

Comment: @Monsieur_Sboob Probably because you're still using `if @pin_number == @pin`, neither will be defined. The first half of the answer explains why.

Comment: Exactly that was the problem ! I fixed it with your help, thanks a lot :) I was still a bit confused when I should use `@`, `@@` or `$` ! It's clearer now !

Comment: @Monsieur_Sboob It's even easier. You never want to use `@@` nor `$`. Both are better done with constants and class instance variables (the class itself is an object and can have instance variables).

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to pass around pin wherever needs. You can pass pin to following method

```
def display_balance(pin)
    pin_check(pin)
    puts "Hello #{name} ! Your balance is $ #{balance}."
  end
```

Now you can call `checking_account.display_balance(1234)`

Comment: Thanks for your help !

However, when I'm trying to give "1235" instead of "1234" to the parameter, the consol still displays "Access authorized: pending transaction" and not "Access denied: wrong PIN".

Do you know why ?